# How to debug Unexpected Token < in Chrome Console

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm getting an error message when I upload a file with AJAX and the error message is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < subdomain.domain.com/:6
```

I clicked on the link and it's showing me the following on that line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

I have no idea if this is the actual error or where the error is coming from. Any ideas on how to debug this?

Comment: that is error page with some html messages which is by default done if you don't handle any execption.

Answer (score 1):

I get this error sometimes when trying to `eval` or `document.write` with contents retrieved from AJAX...

In this regard, I watch the Network activity through the developer tools (*usually F12 on the keyboard*) (accessible in IE, FireFox, Chrome, and Safari.. IDK about the others).. I generally trace back the activities/actions/functions I use and monitor the results using `console.log()`

In the network activity for the AJAX responses I check the **Request Response** to see what the output was and ultimately called to be used in the function. I ended up usually finding HTML formatted errors like a *`Parse error: Unexpected blah blah blah`*

Comment: For future reference; The hint at the far-right is key here. It'll state `requestname:linenumber`. This means  "requestname" is to be found in the network tab. Open it, click "response" (NOT preview!) and find the line number in question.

Answer (score 0):

That means you have `<!DOCTYPE html>` inside script tags

```
<script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
</script>
```

Or in an included javascript file

which obviously you should not

Comment: Thanks, how do I find out where that is coming from? I've got some plugins activated that have JS files.

Comment: hopefully you'll be using some kind of ide or at least an advanced text editor like notepad++ which will allow you to globally search your project files for `<!DOCTYPE html>` and inspect all usages